# How to establish a client server connection outside the LAN?

Tags: vb6, proxy, router, lan

I am unable to establish a connection to the server of my client server app written in vb 6.0.
This is just because that the server of the app is behind a LAN router and the router of the LAN is not in my access so as to configure it. If it is possible to establish a connection so please let me know how? and if it is not possible than how the programs like team viewer and LogMein can establish a connection.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the person who does administer the router to open the port or to give you a VPN tunnel, or to move the server to a lan with lower security requirements. If you have a good reason for needing this they shouldn't make a fuzz about it.

TeamViewer and LogMeIn rely on central systems under their own control. Both the client and the server make an outgoing connection to the central system that patches them through to each other. So on both sides the firewall only has to allow outgoing connections.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the router at the server end you might be able to use UPnP in your server to map the port through the NAT router.

See [Easy UPnP NAT Traversal](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=658823) for a VB6 discussion of the topic.